# How do I merge df1 and df2 by two columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

How do I merge df1 and df2 by two columns (fiels) at clausula on?

For example:

```
dfUltStatus = pd.merge(dfUltStatus, dfDescStatus, 
                  on=['CODIGO_STATUS','SUB_CODIGO_STATUS'], how = 'left')
```

The object is merge the two data frames through these two fields to bring the description field.

Comment: Have a look at this documentation: https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-join-two-pandas-dataframes-on-multiple-columns-in-python

Comment: Tks. But, I had already seen this post. tried but it didn't work ... unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
dfUltStatus = dfUltStatus.merge(dfDescStatus, 
                  on=['CODIGO_STATUS','SUB_CODIGO_STATUS'], how = 'left')
```

?

Comment: Tks  by your tip.
I tried it.
But when I do "yield dfUltEvento" I have the error "<class 'GeneratorExit'>"

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying? Where exactly are you using the `yield`?

Comment: Yes, sure...  Tks by your help and sorry about my english... I not speak English very well rsrs...

Comment: (...)
dfDescStatus=self.executacomandoSQL(consultaDescStatus)
                if not dfDescStatus.empty: 
                           dfUltStatus = dfUltStatus.merge(dfDescStatus, on=['CODIGO_STATUS','SUB_CODIGO_STATUS'], how = 'left') 
                           print('Funcionou')
                yield dfUltEvento            
        except:              
            return sys.exc_info()[0]

Comment: So, your join is working now? What is the dfUlt...? How did you define it? Where did that got initialized?

Comment: Yes, see:

dfUltStatus = dfUltStatus.merge(dfDescStatus, on=['CODIGO_STATUS','SUB_CODIGO_STATUS'], how = 'left')

Thanks by help.

Comment: Ok! Can you please accept the answer / upvote if that;s the case!